# In pygtk, why does importing the gtk module change my locale settings?

Tags: python, pygtk

I was surprised to find out that in a Pygtk program, merely importing the gtk module will change the currently loaded locale. If I run the following test program I get two different results in the print statements:

```
import locale
import pygtk

print "Locale before:", locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, None)
import gtk
print "Locale after:", locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, None)
```

The output:

```
Locale before: C
Locale after: LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8;LC_TIME=en_US.utf8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8;LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8;LC_NAME=en_US.utf8;LC_ADDRESS=en_US.utf8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.utf8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.utf8
```

After the `import gtk` line the locale is configured according to my `LC_xxx` environment variables, as if someone had called `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")`. Is this intentional behavior from pygtk or gtk? Is it documented somewhere?

If I do not want to use the locale settings from the `LC_xxx` family of environment variables, where should I be calling `locale.setlocale`? I want to be sure that the locale I set in my program will not be overwritten by by one of the libraries that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

One should use `gtk_disable_setlocale()` or whatever the language analogue is to bypass locales from GTK. Should be called prior to any subsequent calls of functions that enter the gtk main loop.

That is the intended behavior of GTK, because it supports internationalization, but I am not sure why it changes the locale globally.